# Monad result type does not produce `Either String` on `fail`

Tags: haskell, monads

Given the following function which produces a result wrapped into a Monad:

```
ab :: (Monad m) => Char -> m Bool
ab 'a' = return True
ab 'b' = return False
ab _   = fail "say what?"
```

Following uses work as I would expect:

```
ab 'a' :: [Bool]      -- results in [True]
ab 'c' :: [Bool]      -- results in []
ab 'b' :: Maybe Bool  -- results in Just b
ab 'c' :: Maybe Bool  -- results in Nothing
ab 'a' :: Either String Bool  -- results in Right True
```

But, with `Either String`, `fail` actually produces an exception, although I would expect it to be a `Left` with an error message:

```
> ab 'c' :: Either String Bool
*** Exception: say what?
```

Why is it? Is there a way to change the code above (function implementation, or the way it is applied) so as to produce `Left` in case of failures (yet keeping it generic certainly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is it?

Remember `fail`'s type: `Monad m => String -> m a`. Now, if the monad instance of `Either` was only defined for `Either String`, this would be easy:

```
instance Monad (Either String) where
    fail = Left
    ...
```

However, the actual instance is more general:

```
instance Monad (Either e) where
    ...
```

Therefore `fail`'s type is also more general, even if we constrain it to this specific instance:

```
-- No          v  restriction on e   v
fail :: forall e a. String -> Either e a
--      ^^^^^^^^^^
-- This is implicitly there every time you use a polymorphic function
-- (unless you start toying around with some extensions and move it further
--  to the right or into parentheses, see RankNTypes or similar extensions.)
```

And since `e` isn't restricted to `String`, there's no general way to store the error message in `Left e`. For example, how what should the following example return?

```
example :: Either () () 
example = fail "Example"
```

Even if you use an `Either String a`, the more general instance is still being used. An alternative is a newtype or your own ADT with a fitting instance:

```
data EitherString a  = ELeft String | ERight a

instance Monad EitherString where
    fail = ELeft
    ...


newtype EitherWrap a = Wrapped { unWrap :: Either String a }

instance Monad EitherWrap where
    fail = Wrapped . Left
```

Note that there's [a proposal](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/Libraries/Proposals/MonadFail) to split `fail` from the `Monad` typeclass into a `MonadFail` one.

Comment: Thank you. Then, why the more general instance of `Either e` is still being used? I thought that when I specify `Either String a` as the target - it would have bind the `e` from `Either e` to a `String`. Am I asking too much of the type inference or am I missing something yet?

Comment: @Timur: `fail`'s type in the context of `Either` can be thought as `fail :: String -> Either e a`. There's no constraint for `e`. Given that a special instance for `Either String` would overlap the already existing one, this isn't very feasible.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Looked at the source code (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/Data.Either.html#Either)... Certainly, how would you implement `fail` for a generic type `e` otherwise than its default implementation with an `error`. Thank you, that's clear now!

Comment: Makes sense but still, with introduction of  `MonadFail` , `Either String a` is not  an instance of `MonadFail` It's kinda possible with `IsString` class  but  why isn't it in the standard library? 
```
instance IsString a =>  MonadFail (Either a ) where 
  fail msg = Left $ fromString msg
```

Answer (score 2):

Back in the Day, there was no a `Monad` instance for `Either` in the "standard" libraries at the time.  Instead, this instance was [defined in the mtl library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.0/src/Control/Monad/Error.hs).  However, to make `fail` work as you desire we need a way to convert a string into whatever the type `e` is in `Either e`.  This led to the [`Error`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html#t:Error) class.  Back in the day, the `Monad` instance in mtl had `Error` as a constraint on the `Either` instance of `Monad`.  This was solely to make `fail` Do The Right Thing, and most people thought of `fail` as a bit of a wart on the `Monad` class.  Unfortunately, it meant that you couldn't use any `Monad` operations on `Either` except when your "error" type was an instance of `Error` which wasn't typical or usually desirable.  The orphan instance for `Either` also caused much trouble when a rival monad library, [transformers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers), came along.  Eventually, though, the usefulness of using monad operations on `Either` regardless of the "error" type and the movement the `Monad` instance into base prevailed to cause the constraint to be removed.  Now, though, there is no sensible thing that can be defined for `fail`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Either` is a disjunction, not just success/error. It is often used for representing success/error (because it is convenient), but in general it is not the case.

That's why data constructors are named `Left` and `Right`. They are equal in their rights to represent the value.

For example, it is perfectly OK for me to have `Either Computation Result` or something like that. `Either Gold Money`, etc.

It would probably not be correct if `fail` ended up returning one of the branches of a disjunction.

Comment: Equal in their rights to represent the value, but `(>>=)` is still `Left` biased.

Comment: >>= is `Right` based because in `Either a b` it is not `Either` that is a monad, but `Either a`.

Comment: I said "b__i__ased", not based. `Left k >>= _ = Left k`. And I'm well aware of the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's possible with `Data.String(IsString)` class, i.e. the one used for `OverloadedStrings` extension.

```
instance IsString a =>  MonadFail (Either a ) where 
  fail msg = Left $ fromString msg
```

But I guess there's a reason for it to be not in the standard library